# Check if device is an iPad then stop a jQuery function running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop a function running of the mobile version of a website.

```
function isiPhone(){
return (
    //Detect iPad
    var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
  );
}

if(isiPad){
  myFunction.stop();
}
```

The code checks if the user is on an iPad and is they are I want to stop `myFunction` from executing. I am using the `.stop()` method ([jQuery Docs - Stop)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

When I run this code `myFunction` doesn't stop running. myFunction is a jQuery animation

Comment: Look at what the code is doing. It is setting a local variable...

Comment: Sorry that is just a typo, it is correct in code.

Comment: Than fix the code in your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your `navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null` within `if(....)` statement

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) && (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)!= null)){
  myFunction.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        function isiPhone(){
           var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
           return isiPad;
        }
```

Or, simpler:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)){
  myFunction.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.stop()` method is used to stop an in-progress jQuery animation.  If your `myFunction` variable isn't holding a reference to an animated jQuery object then it will have no effect.  If it is holding a reference to an animated jQuery object then consider passing the parameters to clear the animation queue (in case other animations are running after the one you stop).

If you are trying to stop a javascript function (which is not a jQuery animation) from executing then you need to stop that in a different manner, such as setting a flag that it checks to have it break execution.